# Chrome extension to block email send (Gmail) before review

Tags: web-browser, email, chrome

I'm looking for a browser extension to block myself from sending an email without review. A perfect solution could be a not-so-intrusive behavior, like a silent notification or disabling the button ('send'). Still, I'm not against something more intrusive like a pop-up "Remember to review." or personalized message.

For exemplification, similar behavior is already built-in in Gmail when I write an email with the word "attach" but forget to attach some files. So, I want almost the same thing, but to remember to review the message, a simple reminder to reread it is enough.

Minimum features:

- Chrome extension
- Works for Gmail web client

Plus:

- Also works in Firefox
- Also works with other web clients (Outlook, etc.)
- Without too much customization. Simple is better

I've searched for it in the Chrome extension store without success, and a simple google search didn't give me good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know an extension that does it directly (seems too specific), but it's definitely achievable with browser automation extensions such as [Automa](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/automa/infppggnoaenmfagbfknfkancpbljcca) with a bit of time spent on configuring the routine.

"When visiting a website" trigger with proper regex -> "JavaScript Code" block that disables the button and e.g. adds an unlock button for it should be sufficient.

Comment: I'll accept the answer since it seems the only option. I was trying to avoid automation.
However, I didn't know Automa extension, which looks much more effortless than Selenium, for example (which was my first challenge when I was considering creating automation before creating the question)